# append a string in a view SwiftUI

Tags: swift

I have some piece of Text that I want to be able to be copied onto the user's clipboard with .textSelection, but is there a way for all the pieces of text I have to be able to be copied at the same time?

Here's an example of what I'm talking about, any way I can alter the code so that all the words in test can be copied together?

```
struct Example: View {
   var test = ["hi", "Hello"]
   var body: some View {
      VStack {
         ForEach(0..<test.count) { i in
            Text(String(test[i])
         }.textSelection(.enabled)
      }
   }
:
```

Comment: This doesn't differ much from your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70501207/9607863) about an hour ago

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var test = ["hi", "Hello"]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(test[0..<test.count],
                id: \.self, content: { test in
            Example(content: test)
            })
        }
    }
}
```